# Is there performance advantage to aggregating async operations before proceeding to sync operations in Java?

Tags: java, performance, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I have a Spring Boot MVC app where I have a Java method which:

1. makes HTTP requests to an API service for some information per each user (async)
2. does some business logic with the results (sync)
3. updates database with the results (sync - JDBC)

For HTTP requests I'll be using an async client like Apache HTTP async client. I'm wondering if there's any performance benefit to first perform all the HTTP calls (async operations) in a loop and then have another loop which will do business logic along with updating the DB or it's ok to just have a single loop which combines sync/async operations on each iteration. All operations would use `Future`/`CompletableFuture`:

**2 loops version:**

```java
 public String testWithTwoLoops() throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(1000)
        .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
        .build();
    httpAsyncClient.start();

    List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:3001");
      Future<HttpResponse> responseFuture = httpAsyncClient.execute(httpGet, null);
      futureList.add(responseFuture);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      futureList.forEach(f -> {
        try {
          HttpResponse httpResponse = f.get();
          // perform business logic/update db
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
    }

    return "result";
  }
```

**1 loop version:**

```java
  public String testWithOneLoop() throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(1000)
        .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
        .build();
    httpAsyncClient.start();

    List<CompletableFuture<HttpResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> httpResponseCompletableFuture = apiCallWithBusinessLogicAndDbUpdate(httpAsyncClient);
      futures.add(httpResponseCompletableFuture);
    }

    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
            .join();

    return "result";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - firing all async HTTP requests first would be better
Why - HTTP calls get longer time to complete (so while you execute all the business-logic and db-updates, (all) the HTTP calls are on their way to completion)

Comment: I can’t execute any business logic or db updates before the calls complete so your point is moot

Comment: Sure, even then, firing them all first would help, as they will all start progressing towards completion. You can then ask the completion service (in a loop) to give you "a" finished call and execute the corresponding business-logic (CompletionService.take()). While you do this one by one, all the HTTP calls you fired initially are progressing.